# Spring BeanCreationException due to NoSuchMethodError in Property class

Tags: java, spring, maven, properties, classpath

I am currently trying to start up a server side of an application, built with Maven; the clean install is succesful, but then tomcat7:run fails with the following Spring error message

```
04:21:19,059 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - 
Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'properties' defined in class path resource [context.xml]: 
Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 
org.springframework.core.convert.Property.<init>(Ljava/lang/Class;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;
Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

The concerned bean definition in context.xml is as follows

```
<bean id="properties" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location" value="classpath:server.properties"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

Research shows that these kind of errors are usually related to incorrect JAR versions on the classpath. In this particular application, Spring version 3.2.4.RELEASE dependencies are defined in Maven pom.xml, and checking out the API of the concerned org.springframework.core.convert.Property class it seems that constructor Property(Class objectType, Method readMethod, Method writeMethod, String name) is actually available in this version. Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: Can you provide the complete pom file?

Comment: There is a main pom.xml (10K) which contains four module pom.xmls, one of these is this mentioned server module (8K). Which parts of these would you like to see?

Comment: Right. Then try to build the .war and look in the WEB-INF/lib to see what jars Maven resolves.

Comment: The ...\server\target\server-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war\WEB-INF\lib contains spring-*-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar files

Comment: Yep, I'm no Spring expert, but this looks like a version mis-match if I've ever seen one

Comment: `Property(Class<?> objectType, Method readMethod, Method writeMethod, String name)` constructor is added in version 3.2 of Spring. It looks like you have the `Property` class from prior 3.2 version included in the classpath as a standalone jar file or as part of some "fat" jar.

Comment: There is spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar containing Property class in WEB-INF/lib, which should be OK by version. Is there a way to determine, that if the class is not tried to be used from this jar, then from where? By the way, I also tried changing the property-value syntax, as you suggested in your deleted answer, but got the same exception

Comment: What other jars do you have in WEB-INF/lib? Post a list, if possible.

Comment: Created a dir printout file, and uploaded it here: https://app.box.com/s/j5nru1d5i0pog599b6y8 Please let me know if it is not visible. By the way in the meantime I have also javap'd Property.class from spring-core-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar and it contains public org.springframework.core.convert.Property(java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.reflect.Method, java.lang.String); all right

Comment: Some update: I just ran a mvn dependency:analyze and that reports org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.2.4.RELEASE:compile in this server module among "Unused declared dependencies found". So possibly the Property class is not referred from this jar

Comment: You have a lot of jars in there. Can you provide, also, the complete stack trace?

Comment: It seems that this issue is now solved, please see below answer and my comment. Thank you for your help as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run your java with `-verbose` option.

It shows wich jar has been loaded class from.

Looks like there is a spring jar in the `bootstrap` classloader of your Tomcat - older version of Spring.

Comment: It seems you are right, java verbose reports: Loaded org.springframework.core.convert.Property from .../server/target/apache-tomcat-maven-plugin/activiti-webapp-explorer2/WEB-INF/l‌​ib/spring-core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar. Apparently the root cause was that the Activiti dependencies all had version 5.14; after increasing those to 5.15 the Spring dependencies went up to 3.2.7.RELEASE, and the reported BeanCreationException is not there any more (there is now another BeanCreationException related to JDBC connection, but that I will investigate separately). Thank you for your help on this one.

Comment: How do we add -verbose in eclipse ? Where do we add it ?